When I host my site on my PC In IIS server the email send correctly when i host on my Production server the email does not send
I'm experiencing an issue with sending emails using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient in an ASP.NET Web API project. The emails are supposed to be sent automatically using Hangfire, but I'm encountering an error: Failure sending mail.
public static void sendScheduledEmail(int clientId, string message)
{
    string smtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int smtpPort = 587;
    string smtpUsername = "abc@gmail.com";
    string smtpPassword = "abc1233454";

    try
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient(smtpServer, smtpPort))
        {
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(smtpUsername);
            string recipientEmail = new data_StockTransferInfoModel().GetEmail(clientId, message);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipientEmail))
            {
                mailMessage.To.Add(recipientEmail);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Error("Recipient email not found for ClientID: {ClientId}", clientId);
                return;
            }
            mailMessage.Subject = "Test Email from ASP.NET Web API";
            mailMessage.Body = message;

            client.Send(mailMessage);

            Console.WriteLine($"Email sent successfully.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred while sending email: {ErrorMessage}", ex.Message);
    }
}

this code works correct when i have to send my email on my local IIS server it also send email on my local server but when i host it on my Production server using auto email secduling hangfire it gives me this error [ERR] An error occurred while sending email: Failure sending mail.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mail.corbissoft.com'
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at LuandaryWebAPI.HelperClass.WhatsAppMessages.sendScheduledEmail(Int32 clientId, String message) in E:\WEBAPI_CHMUNIR 29-04-24 backup (2)\WEBAPI_CHMUNIR\LuandaryWebAPI\HelperClass\WhatsAppMessages.cs:line 139
 I dont know what the the issue is in code or on IIS server on PRodcutrion server i fnd to its soltions 

I am also using Hangfire this code is in my startup.cs

            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ClientsController>(controller => controller.SendAutoWhatsappMessage(), Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ClientsController>(controller => controller.SendAutoEmail(),Cron.MinuteInterval(5)); i Tried every solution in INternet but i can find the soultion 
When i use hangfire Recurring job then this Error occurs otherwoese when i call this fucntion in api endpoint then it send email on both Locaally or IIs server


What does this line do? new data_StockTransferInfoModel().GetEmail(clientId, message);

This line get the email of Client like etc@gmail.com and also when it get the Clientemail it aslo save the email record in database

I really want to solve this Error i Tired every posible things but i can find any Any Solution

See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954415/sending-emails-using-hangfire-on-asp-net-core-2-1. Create a separate service and move your send email logic there and just trigger hangfire job in your controller code.

can this api automatically call when i host it on iis server this is causing because the i am write my trigger job in startup.cs file

Still the same error when i host my Applciation IIS server this error occured  An error occurred while sending email: Failure sending mail.
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'mail.corbissoft.com'
